# Prove that ${2n \choose n}= 2{2n-1 \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

So I'm completely new to this, and I have a very basic understanding of how this works. Here is my best attempt at trying to prove this.

${2n \choose n}$

=$\frac{(2n)!}{(n)!(2n-n)!}$

=$\frac{(2n)!}{2(n)!}$

and then

${2n-1 \choose n}$

=$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n)! (2n-1-n)!}$

=$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n)! (n-1)!}$

I have no idea if this is the method to prove this problem, or even if I have done it correctly up to this point. I hit a block in trying to get the ${2n \choose n}$ equivalent to the ${2n-1 \choose n}$.

I am really at a beginner level here, so if you could explain your steps it would be great!

Comment: Hint:  $(2n)!=2n\times (2n-1)!$

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{(2n - 1)!}{(n)! (n - 1)!} = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n) \cdot (n)! (n - 1)!}$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So I'm really new to this, can you explain how that's equivalent? I'm still learning how to work with factorials, and I'm at a real beginner's level.

Comment: I put an explanation in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you made a mistake when you wrote that $(n)!(n)!=2(n)!$. It should be $(n!)^2$. So $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Next, you got that $\binom{2n-1}{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n)!(n-1)!}$. Now just multiply and divide the expression by $2n$. You will get $\frac{(2n)!}{2(n!)^2}$. Hence $2\binom{2n-1}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: This is great thanks for the explanation! I know this is a really basic question, but I'm kinda iffy on working with factorials. Could you explain how the multiplying and diving by 2n works?

Comment: Well, if you multiply and divide by the same number you don't change the expression. Now let's see what we get from this. In the numerator we have $(2n-1)!\times (2n)=(2n)!$. In the denominator it is $(n)!(n-1)!\times (2n)=2(n)!(n-1)!n=2(n)!(n)!$.

Comment: oh, I see. So I didn't know / understand that  (n-1)! * n just equals n!. Thanks for breaking it down!

Comment: It follows from the definitions. $(n-1)!\times n=(1\times 2\times 3\times...\times (n-1))\times n=1\times 2\times...\times n=n!$.

Answer (score 2):

*With very few calculations*:

We can use the recurrence relation
$$\binom nk=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}, $$
which is the basis of the proof of the formula with factorials.
 In particular,
$$\binom{2n}n= 2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=2\binom{2n-1}n,\quad\text
{since}\quad n=(2n-1)- (n-1).$$

Comment: Quite a fine proof too!

Comment: Ok, I put it as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{We know from Pascal's triangle that }\binom m k=\binom{m−1}{k−1}+\binom{m−1}{k}.$$
$$\therefore\binom{2n}n=\binom{2n−1}{n−1}+\binom{2n−1}n=2\binom{2n−1}n$$

$$\text{since }\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n-1}n\text{ since } (2n-1)-(n-1)=n.$$

Comment: Inspired by @Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Noting $2n-n=n, $  we have $${2n \choose n}=\frac{\color{red}{(2n)!}}{\color{green}{(n)!}(n)!}.$$

Also, noting $(2n-1)-n=n-1, $ we have $${2n-1 \choose n}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n)!(n-1)!}.$$

Finally, note that $\color{red}{(2n)!}=2n\times(2n-1)!$ and $\color{green}{n!}=n\times(n-1)!$ and $\frac {2n}n=2$ and we're done.

---

The last note is because $m! = m\times(m-1)\times(m-2)\times...\times2\times1$ and

$(m-1)!=(m-1)\times (m-2)\times...\times2\times1$,

so $m!=m\times(m-1)!$.